# existence of uncountably many subsets of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $\mathbb{N}$ contains uncountably many infinite subsets $(N_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}$ such that $N_{\alpha}\cap N_{\beta}$ is finite if $\alpha \neq \beta$.

I think we have to assume that $\mathbb{N}$ has only countably many subsets of that kind and then arrive at a contradiction due to the finiteness of the intersection of any two distinct subsets between them. But I am unable to find the correct argument. What will be the possible approach here?

Comment: It looks like you want to show that there is an uncountable collection of infinite subsets of natural numbers such that any two distinct subsets from this collection have finite intersection . Is this your problem ? Your indexing is confusing to me .

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/162387 has several other duplicates.